# AutoComplete TextBox for multiple items like stackoverflow tags search section in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I tried to get AutoComplete TextBox for multiple items.

my view looks like

```
  $(function () {
      var availableTags = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.movies));
      function split(val) {
          return val.split(/,\s*/);
      }
      function extractLast(term) {
          return split(term).pop();
      }

      $("#tags")
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind("keydown", function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  })
  .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function (request, response) {              
          response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
      },




  @using (@Html.BeginForm())
   {
    <b>Search Movie</b>
    @Html.TextBox("tags", null, new { id = "tags" })
   @* @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.nam, new { id = "txtSearch", name = "SearchTerm" })*@
    }
```

My controller action method is shown below

```
   public JsonResult GetMovieNames(string term)
    {
        List<string> mnames = db.Movienames(term).ToList();
        var rows = mnames.ToArray();
        ViewBag.movies = rows;
        return Json(mnames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

how to pass movienames(i.e;string list) to availabletags  present in javascript.
In output it shows home/movienames.But i need movie names list into available tags.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `class` attribute to your elements that needs autocomplete feature and use the below code. Check the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)

Check the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) for complete code sample

```
$( ".className" ))
.autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
 $.getJSON( "search.php", {
 //cosntruct it
 }, response );
}
```

**UPDATE:** If MVC is used just change the `search.php` to `\Controller\Search`

Here is the sample code for constructing JSON based output for autocomplete

```
public JsonResult Search(string term)
{
    List<Records> recs = new List<Records>();           
    var rows = recs.ToArray();
    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: i use mvc.so in place of search.php.which i need to use (i mean action method)

Comment: in jquery website they give  .autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
source: function( request, response ) {

response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
},

Comment: i need to pass string array from controller to view(In "availabletags" i need to pass database values).How?Thanks for giving Response...

Comment: @user3145484, keep it in a ViewBag and pass.

Comment: i tried that one also."var availableTags = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.movies));" not works